# _dontEnumPrototype method in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, actionscript

What do *(undocumented)* `_dontEnumPrototype`, `_init` and `_setPropertyIsEnumerable` methods of the [`Object`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) class do ?

---

I'm just asking because I noticed how annoying it is to type the beginning of my fields and methods to make code completion do an ***acceptable*** job. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> I expected a list with stuff that I want to be displayed. Instead I get ugly underscored methods that I never use. So now I'm interested what are they for ? Are they important ?

"Goto Declaration" in FlashDevelop (4.2.3 RTM) takes me to `"[model] Object.as"`.

[image]

After updating to FlashDevelop 4.6.1.30 the methods are still there.

Comment: Hm, very strange.. This is pure Object? Never heard of those, would like to see the answer :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Yes, just write a new class not extending anything, write a method, type in `return ` and open code completion list.

Comment: Well doesn't happen to me - I'm using FlashDevelop 4.5.2.5, Flex 4.6.0 or AIR 3.9.. What do you use?

Comment: @AndreyPopov FD 4.2.3 RTM, Flex 4.6 SDK and no AIR.

Comment: I don't know then.. If it's not from the SDK, then something from the editor and the intrinsic swc.. You are 100% sure it's not proxy or some other stuff? :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov I hid them with a FD option. See the answer. You can try and display them for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering this myself because there is no other article about this like **in the whole internet.**

<kbd>Menu</kbd> → <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Program Settings</kbd> → <kbd>AS3Context</kbd> → <kbd>Lazy Classpath Exploration</kbd>

```
false // to show those methods
true // to hide those methods
```

Just the solution (to hide those methods) no explanation, sorry.

*(I tracked the `[model] Object.as` down to `C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\frameworks\libs\player\11.5\playerglobal.swc`)*